# Несколько запросов к одному скрипту

Tags: php, apache, symfony2

В общем есть контроллер на symfony там загружается и обрабатывается большой CSV файл, по ajax  отправляю файлик он загружается и в while  идет обработка, в это время я на этот же контроллер шлю по таймеру запросы и проверяю сколько записей уже прошло в базу. Соответственно отображаю progress bar.

Проблема в следующем, после того как ушёл первый запрос с файлом скрипт как будто замирает, все запросы по ajax которые дёргают статус доходят до сервера и ждут, когда  обработка файла заканчивается я получаю пачку ответов, равную количеству запросов.

Дело происходит на Apache, linux  стандартные настройки. На Openserver во время обработки файла я получал прогресс.

Comment: Дефолтный механизм сессий блокирует файл на запись и чтение, не позволяя двум запросам существовать одновременно. Скорее всего, у вас именно оно.

Comment: $request->getSession()->save(); В коде пишу так

Answer (score 1):

В общем добавил в цикл 
$request->getSession()->save();
до этого было только вверху контроллера
Если кто знает как сделать progress bar более удобным способом поделитесь.